# Is there a RPC API equivalent of fetching my Ethereum balance by using CURL in the cli?

Tags: metamask, rpc, cli, api

Since metamask connects to a RPC server and passes in the eth address to make a api request. Is it possible to do the same functionality using CURL in the cli to do a basic balance inquiry of an ethereum address?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it’s possible using Infura.

Just checking quick [here](https://piyopiyo.medium.com/how-to-get-ethereum-balance-with-json-rpc-api-provided-by-infura-io-6e5d22d25927), there’s a JSON RPC call you can make using curl.